# Display Node edit under edit tab

Tags: hooks

I would like to know whether the "node edit form" (admin form) can be displayed under the edit tab itself using `MENU_LOCAL_TASK`?

Comment: instead of redirecting to node/%node/edit. I need to show the form under the edit tab itself..

Comment: you want  you have another menu ( url) for edit page? or you want load edit ajaxly?

Comment: Thanks Zhilevan. I want under the same menu itself. I don't want to open the edit page in new tab. want the page under the edit tab itself

Answer (score 1):

I suggest hide default edit tab and create a tab set with [Quick Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module.I mean bypass default drupal menu tab( or hide it completely ) and create your own . this module help you to create a `quicktab set` that click on each item don't need page getting refresh.

> The Quick Tabs module allows you to create blocks of tabbed content,
>   specifically views, blocks, nodes* and other quicktabs*. You can
>   create a block on your site containing multiple tabs with
>   corresponding content. Clicking on the tabs makes the corresponding
>   content display instantly, using jQuery. With the 6.x-2.x branch, this
>   can be done in either ajax or non-ajax mode:
>
> ```
> if you choose ajax mode for your Quick Tabs block (and this is chosen on an individual QT basis), only the content of the active tab
> ```
>
> will be loaded on page load and the content of the other tabs will be
>   loaded via ajax on tab click (this is good for performance if you are
>   loading, for example, several large views)
>       in non-ajax mode the tab content is just hidden / shown on tab-click. This latter method is an ideal way to do something like the
>   Most Popular / Most Emailed stories tabs you see on many news
>   websites, where it is used more as a space-saving device in your
>   sidebar. If however, you want a QT block as the main content of your
>   entire page, then the chances are that ajax mode will be more
>   appropriate.
>
> Once created, the Quick Tabs blocks show up in your block listing,
>   ready to be configured and enabled like other blocks. Multiple Quick
>   Tabs blocks can be placed on a single page.
>
> For theming of the tabs, several styles have been provided for you to
>   choose from (in the 7.x-3.x branch this functionality comes in a
>   separate submodule, Quicktabs Tabstyles), along with the default
>   option of no style, if you prefer to add your own theming instead.

Answer (score 0):

For D7, use [Advanced Form Blocks (AFB)](https://www.drupal.org/project/afb) for specific nodes, but not all/any nodes. Works also for new nodes of any chosen content type.